# Room - Using @get:Query instead @Query

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, koin

This project has MVVM, Room, Koin and Coroutines.

Project code:

```
@Dao
interface MovieDao {
   @get:Query("select poster_path from Movie")
   val getImgPopularMovieList: LiveData<List<String>>
}
```

What means "**@get:Query**" instead "**@Query**" and "**val**" instead "**fun**" in DAO interface?

And how to add WHERE clause without a function to pass parameter or using a constant? (Using mandatorily val instead fun). Example: "select poster_path from Movie WHERE category = :someParameterOrConstant"

Comment: If you want a parameter, you want a `fun`. What makes you think that isn't an option?

Comment: I guess this type of solution is about Single Sorce of Truth with koin integration. And there is a reason to be "val", but I don't know why. I would like to at least add a Constant in WHERE clause like ${Constant.category}

Comment: You can certainly add a constant. What makes you think you can't do that?

Comment: "An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant" When I tried 
"select backdrop_path from Movie WHERE category = ${Constant.category}"

Comment: So where do you define `Constant.category`? Is it actually a `const`?

Comment: Thank you to ask it, I didn't realized it.
I've tried Enum... But I guess that isn't possible to use it...
Now I don't know if I use Constant instead Enum or if exists another way to do it. 
I guess if I change "val" to "fun" won't be in the architecture

Answer (score 3):

I would like to leave this answer, in case someone new in Kotlin like me encounters this.

I was learning codelab about Android, and `@get:Query` mentioned in the project, which lead me to this question, then after a good research I found this concept relates to Kotlin than Android and it is called [Use-site Targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) annotation.

---

#### Annotation Use-site Targets

Simply put, annotation **use-site targets** allow any `@Annotations` in your source code to end up at a very specific place in your compiled bytecode or in the Java code generated by kapt.

Kotlin supports the following values of the use-site targets that correspond to:

- delegate – a field storing a delegated property
- field – a field generated for a property
- file – a class containing top-level functions and properties defined in that file
- get/set – the property getter/setter
- param – a constructor parameter
- property – the Kotlin's property, it is not accessible from Java code
- receiver – the receiver parameter of an extension function or property

Let's use simple class:

```kotlin
class Example(@param:ColorRes val resId:Int )
```

We used the *use-site* of `param` with `@ColorRes`, that will apply `@ColorRes` to the constructor parameter in the generated Java class:

```java
public final class Example {

   private final int resId;

   public final int getResId() {
      return this.resId;
   }

   public Example(@ColorRes int resId) {
      this.resId = resId;
   }

}
```

Let's change the *use-site* to `field`:

```kotlin
class Example(@field:ColorRes val resId:Int )
```

Now `@ColorRes` annotation will be applied to the `resId` field of the generated class:

```java
public final class Example {

   @ColorRes
   private final int resId;

   public final int getResId() {
      return this.resId;
   }

   public ViewModel(int resId) {
      this.resId = resId;
   }

}
```

By using the *use-site* of `get`:

```kotlin
class Example(@get:ColorRes val resId:Int )
```

The getter method of `resId` field will have the `@ColorRes` annotation:

```java
public final class Example {

   private final int resId;

   @ColorRes
   public final int getResId() {
      return this.resId;
   }

   public Example(int resId) {
      this.resId = resId;
   }

}
```

So!

In our Android code:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface MovieDao {

   @get:Query("select poster_path from Movie")
   val popularMovieImageList: LiveData<List<String>>

}
```

The annotation use-site of `get` will require th implementation of `MovieDao` to apply `Query("...")` to getter method of `popularMovieImageList`:

```java
public final class MovieDaoImpl {

   private final LiveData<List<String>> popularMovieImageList;

   @Query("select poster_path from Movie")
   public final LiveData<List<String>> getPopularMovieImageList() {
       ...
   }

}
```

**NOTE**: Previous java code is from my imagination, I have no idea how generated implementation for this Dao by `Room` will look, just to support my explanation.

---

So far!
Why `@get:Query` instead of `@Query`?

Well, from the docs of [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query) we use `@Query` for methods:

> Marks a method in a `Dao` annotated class as a query method.

And from the docs of [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) we don't use the `Annotation Use-site targets` for methods but for `a property or a primary constructor parameter`:

> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter, there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode.

As far as I learned in *Kotlin*, property getter cannot have parameter but instead use methods for that.

I think all other confusions should be clear now.

---

References:

- [Use-site annotation targets - Mastering Kotlin by Nate Ebel](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/programming/9781838555726/8/ch08lvl1sec59/use-site-annotation-targets)
- [Kotlin Annotations - Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-annotations)
- [Advanced Kotlin - Part 2: Use-Site Targets - American Express](http://Technologyhttps://americanexpress.io/advanced-kotlin-use-site-targets/)

Comment: Can you also add suspend to the getter somehow? e.g. `suspend @get:Query("...")`

Comment: Also, can you use other annotations with the `@get` such as `@Transaction`? I need this for embedded relations.

Comment: my apology @Lifes, I am kinda away from Android these days and not sure if I can answer this.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for replying and for your initial answer.